# Why must a monitor be acquired before calling Monitor.Wait()

Tags: .net, multithreading, wait

If a thread calls `Monitor.Wait(lockObj)` on a lock object that it does not currently own then a `SyncronizationLockException` will be thrown.

I don't understand the point of this? If the thread does own the lock and thus can successfully call `Monitor.Wait()` then it's just going to immediately release the lock anyway. Why can't a thread just wait on a lock it does not currently own?

---

Update

I've decided to add a bit more explanation to my question.

From what I understand Wait simply puts the current thread on the monitors wait queue and releases the lock. Later a pulse or pulse all moves one or all threads on the wait queue to the ready queue. Whenever the monitor is released the next (if any) thread on the ready queue is given the lock.

So why can't a wait simply add the thread to the wait queue? Why does it need to acquire the lock to do this? Is there a physical reason for this or just that Microsoft designed the class to force you into using it the correct way?

Now that I think about it I guess putting something on the monitor's wait queue, or moving something to the ready queue is really manipulating the monitor. It would make sense that you would need to *own* the monitor to do this. Is that the right way of thinking about it?

Owe my brain multithreading is hard!

Answer (score 1):

The point of `Monitor.Wait` is to give other threads a chance to grab your lock.

If you don't own the lock in the first place, there's no point; the other threads can grab the lock already.
(Unless some other thread already owns the lock, in which case calling `Wait` would mess up that thread)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Monitor.Wait` without a lock would in most cases introduce a non-deterministic bug. The same if you call `Monitor.Wait` just after acquiring a lock and without setting any shared variables in between of acquiring a lock and calling `Monitor.Wait`.

In particular - if you do not own a lock then you can never be sure that accompanying `Monitor.Pulse` has not been executed before you entered `Monitor.Wait`. Think about a situation when the operating system had suspended thread A just before `Monitor.Wait` call and resumed thread B that is executing `Monitor.Pulse` after doing some computation. All shared variables convince thread B that A is waiting, but this is simply not true yet. And thread A cannot stop executing `Monitor.Wait` at this point.

Also - you may be interested in the idea of Semaphores http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming) . You can wait and signal them without the idea of acquiring them. This is because they hold a state in them. So if you signal first then wait will not lock.

Answer (score 1):

`Monitor.Wait` is used to release a lock and then reacquire it **in an atomic manner**. No other synchronization mechanism in the BCL has that claim to fame. Obviously `Wait` cannot reacquire a lock if one does not already exist. That is why the exception is thrown.

The fact that `Wait` reacquires an existing lock is a very powerful mechanism. It is this fundamental uniqueness in behavior that allows it to be used to build all of the other synchronization mechanisms in the BCL.